# find surd form of $\cos(\frac{7\pi}{12})$ by expanding $a = (1+\sqrt{3}i)(1+i)$

Tags: complex-numbers

after expanding I obtained the following:
$$a = r\cdot \mathrm{cis}(\arctan(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{1-\sqrt{3}}))$$ where the fraction inside arctan further simplifies to $-2 - \sqrt{3}$

how do I proceed?

Comment: The angle is $-\frac{5\pi}{12}$

Comment: Another way, if interesting, is using $$\frac{5\pi}{12}=\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $a=2\exp\tfrac{i\pi}{3}\cdot\sqrt{2}\exp\tfrac{i\pi}{4}=2\sqrt{2}\exp\tfrac{i7\pi}{12}$ we deduce $\cos\tfrac{7\pi}{12}=\tfrac{\Re a}{2\sqrt{2}}=\tfrac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

By de Moivre's theorem:

$\begin{align}
a&=2(\cos \frac{\pi}{3}+i\sin \frac{\pi}{3})\cdot \sqrt{2}(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4})\\
&=2\sqrt{2}(\cos \frac{7\pi}{12}+i\sin \frac{7\pi}{12})=(1-\sqrt{3})+(\sqrt{3}+1)i
\end{align}$

Therefore $$\cos\frac{7\pi}{12}=\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}}{4}$$